# Jquery calendar does not reload after GridView is populated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datagridview, code-behind

I have a simple page with `Jquery datepicker`, `UpdateProgress`, and `GridView` inside of `UpdatePanel`.

Here is a fragment from the page:

```
...
    Select From Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom" name="datepickerfrom"/>
    Select To Date: <input type="text" id="datepickerto" name="datepickerto"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" OnClick="BtnGetData_Click" Text="Get Error List" />
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
           <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />  
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      ...MyGrid...
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
...
```

This is the `code behind` method invoked when clicking on the button:

```
protected void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dateFrom = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form["datepickerfrom"]);
    string dateTo = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form["datepickerto"]);
    InputData data = new InputData(dateFrom, dateTo);
    Session["inputData"] = data;
    gvErrorLog.PageIndex = 0;
    LoadLogErrorData(data);      
}
```

When I first load the page and click on one of the Date's text boxes, `jQuery datepicker` is poped up. When I refresh the page, it pops up as well.

However, after clicking on the button and populating the `GridView` with the data, it is not displayed anymore.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your tag is

```
<input type="text" id="datepickerfrom" name="datepickerfrom"/>
```

This is really the regular html tag.  Microsoft ASP.NET does NOT keep the state (ie in ViewState) of regular html tag.  After postback, the page life cycle effectively creates a new instance of Page (System.Web.UI.Page) object before sending response back to browser as html.

On the other hand, once you change to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepickerfrom" runat="server" />
```

You will see it in postback.  Also the way you capture those 2 dates in code behind is obsolete (only seen in ASP 1.1).

The namespace for your text tag is
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText and the namespace for the server tag is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.  They belong to different namespaces.  Any controls in the HtmlControls are for legacy purpose.

You may change to asp:TextBox and access them from code behind as follows:

```
protected void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string dateFrom = datepickerfrom.Text;  //  -- updated 
    string dateTo = datepickerto.Text;      //  -- updated 
    InputData data = new InputData(dateFrom, dateTo);
    Session["inputData"] = data;
    gvErrorLog.PageIndex = 0;
    LoadLogErrorData(data);  
}
```

If you insist on your tags, you can add a hidden variable and update those hidden variable on change event of your textboxes.

I assume your textboxes are set up like the following

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%=datepickerfrom.ClientID%>").datepicker();
    $("#<%=datepickerto.ClientID%>").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: When changing to this, after the post back, datepicker control is not displayed anyway

Comment: how u setup your datepicker?

Comment: $(function () {
    $("#MainContent_ucMainDisplay_datepickerfrom").datepick();
    $("#MainContent_ucMainDisplay_datepickerto").datepick();
}); This way calendar is displayed first time the page is loaded

Comment: when you say it's "not" displayed, u mean u don't see a calendar popup after you click on it? or u expect to see a calendar popup right after postback without user intervention?

Comment: User clicks on a text box and calendar will popup

Comment: something fishy with the jQuery. once u put any function with $(function() { ... }).. it should run once document is in ready state.  can u debug?  ie put some console.log statement .. and see if it's running within..

Comment: I have the following: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=datepickerfrom.ClientID%>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89740/discussion-between-achan-and-gene).

Comment: Basically, after clicking the button, both textboxes objects are null.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my problem here:

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2010/08/jquery-datepicker-does-not-work-after.html